# React useEffect hook referencing incorrect values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on creating a component for an external library I want to use in my project ([noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider)).

Currently I have this as my `Slider` component:

```
function Slider(props) {
  const { defaultMin, defaultMax, step } = props;
  const sliderElement = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!sliderElement.current) {
      return;
    }

    noUiSlider.create(sliderElement.current, {
      connect: true,
      start: [defaultMin, defaultMax],
      step,
      range: {
        min: [defaultMin],
        max: [defaultMax],
      },
    });

    if (props.onUpdate) {
      sliderElement.current.noUiSlider.on('update', props.onUpdate);
    }

    if (props.onEnd) {
      sliderElement.current.noUiSlider.on('end', props.onEnd);
    }
  }, []);

  return <div ref={sliderElement} />;
}
```

here I wait for the DOM element to be available, then create the noUiSlider instance on that DOM element (`div` i return). I also attach some event handlers inside the effect (onUpdate and onEnd).

The usage of the `Slider` component is like this...

```
// custom hook that just sets state
const [min, max, setMinMax] = useSlider(10, 300);

const handleEnd = () => {
  // these are outdated :(
  console.log(min, max);
}

<Slider 
  defaultMin={10} 
  defaultMax={300} 
  step={10} 
  onEnd={handleEnd} 
  onUpdate={setMinMax} 
/>
```

The issue I am running into is that inside `handleEnd` when I want to reference `min` and `max`, they are the initial values and not the values that I expected to be updated.

How do I retrieve updated values, from within the same scope, from a function I call inside `useEffect`?

I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8893195vk0) example to show this in action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem comes from the way you call `useEffect` in your `Slider` component. You added `[]` as second parameter, which prevents your effect to be called more than once. So it's just called one time after first render, then never again, and so it keeps the old `onEnd`, holding outdated values for min and max.

From [React's doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) :

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.

Replace `Slider.js` with this and it works :

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import noUiSlider from 'nouislider';

function Slider(props) {
  const { defaultMin, defaultMax, step } = props;
  const sliderElement = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    noUiSlider.create(sliderElement.current, {
      connect: true,
      start: [defaultMin, defaultMax],
      step,
      range: {
        min: [defaultMin],
        max: [defaultMax],
      },
    });

    if (props.onUpdate) {
      sliderElement.current.noUiSlider.on('update', props.onUpdate);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (props.onEnd) {
        sliderElement.current.noUiSlider.on('end', props.onEnd);
      }
      return () => {
        sliderElement.current.noUiSlider.off('end');
      };
    },
    [props.onEnd],
  );

  return <div ref={sliderElement} />;
}

export default Slider;
```

Some remarks here :

- `props.onChange` is never defined nor used in your `Slider` component. I discarded it.
- `useEffect` has to be split into two `useEffect`s :

  - One handling the slider creation and connecting the update function (which doesn't need to be updated since it always keeps a valid reference to `setMinMax` in `useSlider.js`)
  - The other updating just the end event, when `props.onEnd` changes (which is actually... on every render, see `index.js > handleEnd`). **Don't forget to clean up the event listener.**

Comment: This breaks the app.

Comment: Then you have other problems (I'll check), but this is the right start for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the thought @Strebler. Unfortunately i have it only rendering once because otherwise it would re-instantiate noUiSlider every time it re-rendered. I tried putting my props into that array (i.e. `[props.onEnd, props.onUpdate]`) but since those function props themselves don't update, that is essentially the same as `[]`.

Comment: `props.onEnd` does actually update since you recreate the function on every render in index.js. I'm trying to split your `useEffect` into two `useEffect`s. Let's see where this goes.

Comment: @Strebler The `if (!sliderElement.current)` blocks aren't needed in either `useEffect`.

Comment: @Adam Right, I just kept the original code as is with these checks. I'll edit for a cleaner answer.

Comment: I noticed this solution causes the events to fire exponentially more every time the slider is changed and the eventually the end value doesn't update. That may be an issue with the `noUiSlider` package OP is using though.

Comment: Yes just saw the same thing. I'm on it.

Comment: @Adam Fixed. Just needed to clean up the `end` event in the second `onEffect`. Check my update.